# Using pre_get_posts for taxonomy post count

Tags: taxonomy, pre-get-posts

I am trying to use pre_get_posts to display a custom number of posts on my taxonomy category pages.  I can get this to work for a single post type (taxonomy) but if I try to use more than one, say in an array, I cannot get it to work.  I am not great with php and a little direction here would be awesome.  Here is what I am working with now:

```
// Change the number of posts that show up on the taxonomy template 
function custom_tax_post_count ( $query ) {
    if (($query->is_tax('taxonomy_1') ))      
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tax_post_count' );
```

I would like something like this:

```
// Change the number of posts that show up on the taxonomy template 
function custom_tax_post_count ( $query ) {
    if (($query->is_tax(array('taxonomy_1', 'taxonomy_2')) ))      
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tax_post_count' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question I just implemented it wrong when testing it on my end (mis-typed the taxonomy).

This is correct:

```
// Change the number of posts that show up on the taxonomy template 
function custom_tax_post_count ( $query ) { 
  if (($query->is_tax(array('taxonomy_1', 'taxonomy_2')) ))
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' ); 
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tax_post_count' );
```